# how many users typically use the "forgotten password" flow?

Tags: passwords, user-experience, forgot-password

I was wondering what the "standard" usage rate of the "forgot my password" flow is on other ecommerce/industry websites? Right now not that many people go through the "forgot my password" link on my website, but that's mainly because most people don't have passwords. I'm in the process of installing a new login (which will encourage people to create passwords), so I anticipate that the number of people who go through the "forgot my password" link will go up, but I don't have any real baseline to compare it against.

So does anybody know what the typical percentage of users executing the "forgotten password" flow is?

A typical user will probably be prompted to log in once every four weeks. Our password requirements are currently minimal.

Comment: It depends on what target audience is using the site and what the site is about, if it is a site where you login regulary or not, but I think it is about 10 per cent.

Comment: this totally depends on the type of service. there are ecommerce sites that i visit perhaps once or twice a year where i *always* use the forgotten password link as a part of the login flow. typically, this is the kind of sites that don't let me set my own passwords to begin with, and don't ask me to change it upon first login. in a few of cases like this i simply haven't been able to bother either to learn the password or to change it.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be on the pro webmaster version of stack overflow.

However, I think it depends primarially on website content and user base.  If your site is the sort where you login once every few months, then you will probably have a higher proportion of people using the forgotten link.

If it's one people login to every day, like facebook, the % will probably be a lot lower.

It's also going to depend on your password policies.  If you require non alpha-numeric digits then your going to have a lot more requests.

It shouldn't really matter what % of people use it, as long as the logic behind it is secure and doesn't allow for exploitation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think these numbers are available as they are dependent on many different factors:

- How often do the users access the service?
- Are logins stored in a cookie, if so, for how long?
- Are there any restrictions on the password such as minimum length?
- What are the drawbacks of creating a new account (any loss of information or just the name?)
- Is it a service that typically needs to be accessed from multiple machines

... are a few parameters that come to mind.

Comment: Some parameters to my question, then:

Users may access the service every day, or may not access it for a month (or so) at a time. The user will be prompted to login again after four weeks of inactivity.

Right now there are no restrictions on the password (it can be a single character), but we're working on making our restrictions more strict. 

Someone who started a new account would need to input a new username and their shipping, etc. information.

Answer (score 0):

On the many platforms I've managed, it has mostly been a common flow. But it depends a lot on the platform, on the formality and function of it. While it will be normal on a simple blog-like social media, you won't see it that often on websites where there is money involved, or at least this is what I have seen on my experience.

> Our password requirements are currently minimal.

I'm pretty sure this has a lot to do with your low percentage, but if you don't carry any sensitive information, you shouldn't change it.